# How to efficiently stream millions of records from .NET to SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I have a C# .NET program that processes millions of records a few at a time and then stores them either in a flat file or a SQL Server database.

Currently, to store them in the SQL Server database the program writes all the records to a flat file and then uses bcp to import into SQL Server.

Is there a more efficient method that bypasses the need to write every record to the hard disk before importing into SQL?

Comment: Have you looked at [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) to load the data to the database?

Answer (score 5):

Consider using the [`SqlBulkCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy) class in the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace. You can use it like this:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
{
    conn.Open();
    {
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.MyTable";
        DataTable dt = BuildMyData();
        try
        {
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
        }
        catch (Exception ex){Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);}
    }
}
```

The `WriteToServer` method is overloaded and will accept 3 different param data types:

- `DataRow[]`
- `DataTable`
- `IDataReader`

Comment: You can also pass it an IDataReader in case you want to stream results.

Comment: Thanks! - I'll look into this and let you know how it works.  By the way, is it reasonably efficient to write one or a few data rows at a time?  Or should I aim to store as many as is reasonable in memory before writing to server?

Comment: @JeffMH, the bottleneck will most likely be the roundtrips between the database and the application, so including as many rows as you can per batch would probably be fastest. As with all performance issues, do a few benchmarks to be sure.